# Why does my Android Studio app fail to run on an Android device?

Tags: java, android, grid-layout

I have built the Connect 3 Game in Android Studio 3.0.1 but when I try to run it on a Samsung Android device it fails to run displaying the message `Unfortunately, Connect 3 Game has stopped.`

The Logcat window in Android Studio displays a lot of messages such as;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stephenlearmonth.connect3game/com.example.stephenlearmonth.connect3game.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.GridLayout
```

I have tried replacing `import android.widget.GridLayout;` with `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;` in my `MainActivity.java` file but I get the error message `Cannot resolve symbol 'GridLayout'.`

I have set `minSdkVersion` in my `gradle.build` file to `19`.

Start of MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.stephenlearmonth.connect3game;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stephenlearmonth.connect3game"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

start of activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.stephenlearmonth.connect3game.MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="368dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

The Android phone displays the message `Unfortunately, Connect 3 Game has stopped.`

The Logcat window of Android Studio 3.0.1 reports the following output;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stephenlearmonth.connect3game/com.example.stephenlearmonth.connect3game.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.GridLayout
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3150)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.GridLayout
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
   at com.example.stephenlearmonth.connect3game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:147)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
   at com.example.stephenlearmonth.connect3game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:147) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.stephenlearmonth.connect3game:drawable/board" (7f060054)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060054 a=-1 r=0x7f060054}
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4017)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3929)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3779)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:776)
   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4001)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:513)
   at android.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:285)
   at android.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:281)
   at android.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:277)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
   at com.example.stephenlearmonth.connect3game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:147) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Check this `drawable/board" (7f060054)  is not a Drawable`!

Comment: @Enzokie How do I use your comment to solve this problem?

Comment: I need to know if `board` is an image?

Comment: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.stephenlearmonth.connect3game:drawable/board" (7f060054)  is not a Drawable (color or path)

Comment: in the layout (`activity_main.xml`), `android:background="@drawable/board"` causes the issue because the referenced `board` can't be loaded as background image. Remove that line and it should work (or crash at some other place) and then you can figure out why it's not a proper drawable (i.e. an image file or an xml file describing something drawable https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource)

Comment: Yes ```board``` is an image. But there isn't a problem running the app in the emulator.

Comment: In your drawable folder did you notice anything like `(v24)` beside the name of your image like e.g. `board (v24)` ?

Comment: @Enzokie Thanks, I've fixed it! I moved the board and counter image resources from the ```drawable-v24``` folder into the ```drawable``` folder and it works. What is the difference between these 2 folders?

Comment: All the images/assets found in the drawable folder will be available in all devices regardless of the Operating Sytem version meanwhile all images/assets found within drawable-v24 will only be available in devices running 24 or above. Your emulator seems running the latest os while your device is below 24.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the board and counter image resources from the `drawable-v24` folder into the `drawable` folder and it works.